# Difference between memory address of a handle to a specific process and handle to the exe module

Tags: c++, assembly, memory, reverse-engineering, memory-address

I am currently studying reverse engineering and inner workings of the memory. I made a simple program that can access another processes memory and read the the specified address. This works without a problem and it is not the focus of my question.

I would like to understand more in-depth how exactly the application looks in the memory and I would like to know the general look of it (Scheme or whatever).

To be more specific I do not understand the following:
**I have an application called TestApp.exe. It has 2 variables in the stack which I am trying to read using another app MemoryReader.exe**

1. **The handle to the process TestApp.exe has the address 0x12C.**
   My first question is **what exactly starts at the address 0x12C**. Is this the starting address of the entire exe, or some meta data to the exe?  **The module has the address of 0x00250000 which is quite a far away from the handle itself making me wonder what is between those two**. Please elaborate.
2. **I have two variables with the address 0x012BD1F8 and 0x012BD1FC. Both are in the stack.** Since they were initialized in the scope of the main right after each other, it makes sense that they are allocated in the stack right next to each other. As we can see the offset is exactly 4 bytes which fits.

However what I do not understand is **why do the offsets from the base address (Module address) to the variables change each time I launch the program?** Is the program not structured the same way and therefore should not it allocate the memory in exactly the same way except on a different address meaning that the offsets should stay the same? What am I missing? From what I understand there must be something dynamic that changes between the variable addresses and the base address of the module, my question is what it is and why? Please explain.

Thank you.

Comment: Note that a handle is a handle, not a memory address. For example opening a file may return a handle that is internal to the OS and it knows what to do with is, it doesn’t have any actual address. So is 0x12C a handle or an address? Otherwise memory addresses are often randomized to make attacks more difficult.

Comment: 0x12c is the value of the handle. It is NOT the address of the HANDLE variable. You are saying that handle is more similar to a descriptor than a pointer. As far as I know handles are pointers that are more "abstract". You do not care what it does or where it points. It points to an object that is what you care about. So it has to point to some part of the memory where the exe is or am I wrong?

Comment: A process handle does not locate a process in RAM, just like a file handle does not locate a file on disk. Handles are just small numbers handed out by the OS, and are always backed by an invisible data structure.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/rammap and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/vmmap

Comment: If you really want to know about these things you should get a copy of [Windows Internals](https://www.amazon.com/Windows-Internals-Part-architecture-management/dp/0735684189/ref=dp_ob_title_bk) - doesn't have to be the latest edition. This is for Windows, obviously - I assume there are similar references for Linux (though I don't have any specifics).